# Questions about Java upcasting/downcasting and inheritance pripority

Tags: java, class, inheritance, binding, casting

Having trouble understanding the intricaies of upcasting/downcasting, and static binding and dynamic bidning in these cases. Please consider the following classes and interface example:

```
 public class Marsupial {   private String name;
         Marsupial(String name) {    
         this.name = name;    
         }
         void eats() {   
         System.out.println("Eats #1");   
         }
         String getName(){    return name;    
         }
         }


    abstract class Herbivore extends Marsupial {
         Herbivore(String name) {
         super(name);    
         }
         void eats() {
         System.out.println("Eats #2");    
         }
         abstract void chews(boolean b); 
         }


    interface Australian {   
    public void greets(Koala k); 
    }


    public class Koala extends Herbivore implements Australian {
         Koala(String name) {
         super(name);   
         }
         public void greets(Koala k) {
         System.out.println("G'day mate!");
         System.out.println(getName() + " " + k.getName() );   
         }
         void chews(boolean b) {

        System.out.println("Yum yum!");   
         }
         void chews(int i) {    System.out.println("Delicious!");    
         }
         void likes(Koala k) {
        greets(k);
        k.greets(this);   }    
        }
```

Now when I make a driver class to use all of the classes I notice some odd things happening that I am not sure why.

For example,

```
public class Driver {   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Marsupial m = new Marsupial("Kate");
    Marsupial m2 = new Koala("Kim");
    System.out.println(m.getClass() == m2.getClass());
               }    
}
```

This turns out to be false. They are not the same class. So what is happening here exactly. We have Marsupial on the left and something else on the right. So does what's on the right the only thing that matters when we are calling methods? When the compiler runs and looks at methods does is check the right side of the equals operator and say ok this is such and such class, therefore use the methods of the class defined on the right side when figuring out whose class to use.

Also,

if inside the main method I wrote:

```
Marsupial m = new Koala("jack");
m.eats();
```

This prints out Eats #2. Now is this because since Koala does not have a eats method is just goes back one level up the chain, so the next level up would be Herbivore and since that has an eats() method that is what gets called, is that the idea there?

Another example in the main method:

```
Herbivore h = new Koala("June");
((Marsupial)h).eats();
```

Here the thing that throws me off is that we can use abstract classes as a reference to actual objects, like here Herbivore is an abstract class therefore cannot be instaniated, but it can be assigned to a class that does instantiate an object.
But what confuses me most is that now we are in the Koala class and we call the eats() method but then we UPCAST the variable to Marsupial. So does that automatically put us in the Marsupial class and therefore anytime we call a method even if its in other classes the Marsupial class method is the one that gets called since we typecasted it to Marsupial, therefore its Eats #1.

Another area of confusion is if we do this in main:

```
Australian a = new Koala("Khloe");
a.chews(true);
```

It's werid seeing an interface be assigned to a subclass instantiation. It confuses me what would get called with a.chews(true). So since it's been defined as a Koala object then we are IN the Koala class and must use Koala methods if they exist, and if not there we go one level up to check that they have that method and so on and so fourth. But here the method is invalid. So does it only work if Australian had a prototype method in there and Koala defined it? then it would work? Is that the idea behind setting interfaces as objects of their subclasses? Even though Koala has that method since Australian does not, it will not work.

And if we have the code in main like:

```
Herbivore h = new Koala("Stacy");
h.chews(true);
```

this will print out "Yum yum" only because Herbivore had that prototyped undefined method and Koala defined it. But if Herbivore didn't have that prototype method is wouldn't work.

The last question I have is if this were run in main:

```
Herbivore h = new Koala("Kali");
h.chews(4);
```

This won't work because despite the fact that Koala has this method in there, it's not defined in Herbivore, so it's invalid.

Please help, any corretions or information you could provide would be very helpful.

Thank you

Comment: I lost count of the number of questions here;  but all of them see to be of the why don't you try it and see variety. It would have taken less time than composing this question(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to all is one: as far as
the JVM is concerned it doesn't
care one bit about the *variable*
type, but only the actual type (the
one used with the `new` keyword)
. Variable types are for the
**compiler** only to ensure type
safety as early in development
possible.

Comment: A conventional viewpoint on this is that variables have a declared type and objects have a runtime type. The declared type tells you what methods you're allowed to call on an instance. If a subtype has the method but the declared type doesn't, you can't call it. The runtime type determines which version of an instance method actually executes. It's the override in the runtime type that wins, if there is one.